# iOS: Multiple launch images

Tags: ios, splash-screen

Is it possible to provide multiple launch images instead of just one Default.png launch image? My goal is, that you have for example 5 different launch images and for every application start it shows another one.

Just in case someone responds with that, I know that there is the possibility to have different launch images for different configurations (e.g. screen orientation). But that's not what I'm looking for. I'd like to have different launch images for exactly the same configuration, with the only variable different being the time of the launch.

Answer (score 4):

Judging from [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12), I don't believe it's possible. You have some latitude in configuring different launch images for Custom URL Schemes or even to localize them, but other than that, since they are specified in the .plist file so that iOS handles them quickly before your app is processing, that's as much latitude as you get...

Comment: that's right. the plist - as well as the images - are inside the signed "bundle". If you changed anything within that bundle this would invalidate the signature and your app wouldn't even launch

Comment: Thanks. That's what I assumed. But I still have the hope that there's something I missed.

Answer (score 2):

There are rumors that it's possible to load default image from `Document` folder:

- set path in info.plist `../Document/Default.png`
- on each app launch override that `Default.png` with one of your predefined images
- *on first launch the start-up screen will be black

PS. I didn't try it, so can't say that it works. And even if it works you can meet problems with Apple review process.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look into that.

Comment: Anyone try this? Sounds very interesting.

Comment: this *works* in iOS7 as well, but haven't tried submitting yet.  The path to set, btw, is ../..Documents/foo.png - basically you need to get outside of the app bundle altogether.

Answer (score -1):

Would be possible if you would insert your launch images using javascript/jquery vs. entering plain HTML.

In your script you would have to specify your logic for what splash screen should be used when. Then use this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   (function() {
      var a;
      if(navigator.platform==="iPad"){
         a = window.orientation === 90 || window.orientation === -90  ? 
             "landscape.jpg":"portrait.jpg"
         } else {
         a = window.devicePixelRatio === 2 ?
              "retina.jpg" : "startup.jpg"
         }
     document.write('<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="'+a+'"/>')
     })()
 </script>
```

Your logic would have to add some variable to the images name. So if it's time, you will have

```
 landscape-Morning.jpg
 landscape-Noon.jpg
 landscape-TeaTime.jpg
 landscape-Evening.jpg
```

Same for the other images.

Haven't tried this but since you can use javscript to set which image to be displayed depending on orientation it shouldn't be a problem to set which image depending on time of day.

Comment: assuming you are talking webapp... :-)

Comment: Sorry. It's a native app. But thanks for the answer anyway. I think it'll be helpful to other people searching for that.

Comment: This won't work, since the launch image is choose by the system while you app is loading.

Comment: @DiogoTridapalli: I'm have been doing this in a web app for some time, so please care to provide an example/source/reasoning

Comment: @frequent For native apps launch images can't be defined by code as far as I know. You can define using Asset Catalog or a specific Storyboard. It's not recommended to use file names anymore. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog.html