# Change the launch image of an app on every launch

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa

I want to change the launch image of my app each time I open it. I've searched on Google and I've found two approaches:

1. Set my launch image name in the plist config file, and replace the image file each time.
2. Delete the launch image property in the plist each time the app launches, display another imageview or uiview, and change the image of the imageview;

The first way, some people said that Apple might reject the app or it may not be approved. Is this likely to be the case?

The second way, it takes a long time after my app is configured and loaded and the app displays a black screen during the loading itself.

Comment: I am not sure either way will get accepted by apple. I am pretty sure your not meant to be changing the launch image, except for if you did an update to the apple app store. I am pretty sure I have read this somewhere but I can't remember where so I have nothing to back this up with at the moment.

Comment: You can also use solution #2 with a "common" splash screen that animates into your new image ?

Comment: You'll get rejected if you don't provide a launch image, quoting the human interface guideline "Launch image (**required** for all apps)"

Comment: Duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722357/ios-multiple-launch-images

Comment: @rdurand you mean that the only way is to show a common image at first ,and change another image after the app is fully loaded?

Comment: i don't know wether it will be ok if i replace the "Default.png" file by another each time.

Comment: @yudun1989: yes, that's what I mean, and I don't know if it's ok to change it at every launch..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend you to do this in code, aka display a "virtual" launch screen of your own using **UIImageView**.

What you want to achieve is impossible, ipas (and thus their contents, including Info.plist) are signed when you archive your app. That means that any modification you make will break the signature, and so you'd need to resign it to make it executable again. The only way to achieve this is to sign your contents again and submit the app to the AppStore once more which kinda invalidates your argument.

Go for the UIImageView approach, I know it won't look that nice but it's the closest you can get given the constraints Apple's ecosystem imposes.

Comment: I think the UIImageView option can look good if you handle the animation nicely !

Comment: -1 for `apks`. `APKs` are android not iOS. Will remove if corrected.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is **NO** you are not allowed to do this. This is because the image that you would have to modify is `Default.png` which is the launch image name which is located in the main bundle of the project, and it is not allowed to edit/amend/modify files in the main bundle of an iOS project.

This is because the contents of the main bundle are cryptographically (Think that's how it's spelt) signed as part of the Apple App store submission. So in modifying the contents within the main bundle could cause the application to stop running.

This also goes against the [Apple submission guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html).

Also Whilst some have suggested doing it through code with animation after it launches you will still need a launch image as it is part of the apple human interface guidelines. All apps must have a launch image.

The only time that you can have different launch images is when your basing it on device and/or retina display and/or orientation.

Here are some of the ones you can use.

```
Default.png
Default@2x.png
Default-568h.png or Default-568h@2x.png
Default-Portait.png
Default-Portait@2x.png
Default~ipad.png
Default-Portait~ipad.png
Default@2x~ipad.png
etc
```

Answer (score 2):

the launch image itself isn't changeable as it is in your bundle. the best way is to show a UIImageView as soon as you can.

that means: applicationDidFinishLaunching should just put up the window and an image view and schedule the real work later. Return YES ASAP -- that way, iOS will think your app has launched and show your window with the uiimageview

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // show the main window, overlay with splash screen + alpha dissolve...
        UIImageView *splashScreen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
    [self.window addSubview:splashScreen];        
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        // in the method do all you normally do
    [self performSelector:@selector(delayedLaunch:) withObject:options afterDelay:0.1];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{splashScreen.alpha = 0.0;}
                     completion:(void (^)(BOOL)) ^{
                             [splashScreen removeFromSuperview];
                     }
    ];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Launch image is not the same as splash. Launch images suppose to give the first impression of the app while it's loading. An interstitial between the launch of the app and the actual interface being initialized and put on screen.

Comment: Name it what you like. I agree but many people use the launch image as splash :)